# How to show callout for pin on map without tapping on it?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit, mkannotation

I have an app with map and in it there are some pins with their annotations.

I don't understand how to show a particular pin's annotation without tapping on it.

Comment: You need to get your terms right. A pin **IS** an annotation view. If you add annotations to a map, the map asks you to provide annotation views for each pin that's visible, automatically. I'm guessing that you're talking about callout bubbles? You want to know how to display a callout bubble on a map pin without the user having to tap on it?

Answer (score 6):

Callouts are generally shown when the annotation is "selected". While this is generally achieved by a user tapping on the annotation view (i.e. the pin), you can also programmatically "select" the annotation:

```
mapView.selectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
```